# How to import a csv file from hdfs into pandas dataframe using WebHDFS REST API?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, http, webhdfs

One can read a `csv` file from a `http` URL into a `pandas` dataframe.

For example, this code would work:

```
import pandas as pd
url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cs109/2014_data/master/countries.csv"
pd.read_csv(url).head()
```

How do I use this kind of `http` "path" if my file is in HDFS and I would like to use the WebHDFS REST API to read the file `/share/my_project/my_file.csv` from HDFS into a `pandas` dataframe?